# Step to integrate sales force with Liferay

Tags: salesforce, liferay, integration, liferay-6

I want to integrate Liferay 6.2 CE with sales force. Anyone can suggest me details for the same using which I can integrate sales force with liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6632067), there is a mention of a custom portlet for the integration.